# Is there a way to output something if the user hasn't responded for a certain amount of time?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm messing around with Linux Bash Shell Scripting for a class and have this written so far:

```
#! /bin/bash
        num=0
        while [ $num -lt 1 ]
        do 
                echo "What is your name?"
                read name
                echo "Your name is $name? Respond with Y or N"
                read response
                if [ $response == "Y" ]; then
                        echo "What an interesting name $name"
                        num=1
                        break
                elif [ $response == "N" ]; then
                        echo "Why would you lie $name? Wait that's not even you>
                        continue
                else
                        echo "Why don't you respond $name, or are you lying?"
                        continue
                fi
        done
```

It's a simple program that asks the user for their name. Then they type in their name and it asks the user if that's their name and they respond Yes(Y) or No(N). At this point I want there to be a timer that if the user doesn't respond for 5 seconds then it displays "Why don't you respond $name, or are you lying?". Is there anyway to do this? Thank you and I appreciate your answers :)

I looked up possible solutions and only saw the sleep command come up. I'm not sure how I could implement this as my understanding of the sleep command is that it will stop the program and wait however much time before continuing instead of running alongside my code.

Comment: `echo "Why would you lie $name? Wait that's not even you>` - quote mismatch, post correct you you wrote and ran

Comment: This might help: `read -t 5 response; if [[ $? -eq 142 ]]; then echo "timeout without input"; fi`

Comment: re quote mismatch: Learn to copy/paste your code into https://shellcheck.net and fix any flagged problems. You'll need `#!/bin/bash` (or what ever shell you want it checked for) as the first line. Good luck.

Comment: You don't say which OS you are using, but on Unix-like platforms, you should find the command `timeout`, which runs a child process with a timeout. See _man timeout_.